# How do you read the value assigned to an AngularJS directive

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have an angular directive that is a custom attribute that possibly can contain a value like so:

```
<div my-directive="myVal"></div>
```

How do I read myVal (as a string) from inside my directive's link function?

Answer (score 39, accepted):

The passed value is on the attributes object passed as the third argument to the link function. It's under a property matching the name of the directive.

```
app.directive('myDirective', function() {
   return {
       restrict: 'A',
       link: function(scope, elem, attr) {
            //read the passed value
            alert(attr.myDirective);
       }
   }
});
```

Comment: It shows that the directive is restricted to being used as an attribute. It's actually optional, as "A" is the default value.  Other values are any combination of: `A - attribute`, `E - element` or `M - comment`.

Comment: how we can get taht value in a controller ?

Comment: @Timmz, you could put in on your $scope inside of there, and get it in your controller. Or you could put it on a service, that was also referenced by your controller.

Comment: I asked a similar question here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25749703/get-value-of-a-directive-from-the-controller/25750342 could you please take a look. thank you in advance .