# Get value of a directive from the controller

Tags: angularjs

I'im new to AngularJs, I'm trying to access the value of '**data-page**' when it's '**Active**'  from my Controller (the pager is generated from a third party plugin) 
Example: in the following example what i'm trying to get is the value:  3

```
  <ul class="pagination pagination-sm">
    <li class="footable-page-arrow">
       <a data-page="first" href="#first">«</a>
    </li>
    <li class="footable-page active">
       <a data-page="3" href="#">4</a>
    </li>
    <li class="footable-page">
       <a data-page="0" href="#">1</a>
    </li>
    ...
    ...
  </ul>
```

Edit folowing a suggestion
I added a directive:

```
  .directive('dataPage', function pageDirective() { // do the name dataPage Wrong ? 

    return {
        restrict: 'A',
        link: function link(scope, element, attributes) {
            scope.page = attributes.dataPage;
            alert(scope.page);             // this one should i get the right value ?
        }
    }

})
```

And I added an alert in the controller just to know what is inside:

```
  $scope.fooFunc= function(){ 
     alert($scope.page); /*I supposed the value is now 
                           avelaible in the controller scope, still get **undefined** */
  }
```

Comment: can you please be more elaborate? which plugin are you using or can you setup a plunker??

Comment: I'im using Footable Plugin: http://fooplugins.com/footable-demos/

Comment: It should just be `attributes.page` - Angular will strip the `data` part for you. Same for the directive name.

Comment: JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/asktog45/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your question is really incomplete, but I'll do my best to try to answer it, since you specifically asked for my help in another thread.

**SPECULATING:** It seems like *maybe* you're trying to update the 'active' state of a DOM element, and have it update some data based on some paging index.

#### You probably don't need a new directive

You *might* be going about this the wrong way.

In Angular, the idea is to have your *controller* "control" all of your "business logic" for the page. The "business logic" being "what should I display and when?" This includes both your class *and* what data you want to display.

```
app.controller('MyCtrl', function($scope, someService) {
  // initialize your "data page" to something
  $scope.dataPage = 0;

  // watch for changes to dataPage
  $scope.$watch('dataPage', function(dataPage) {
    // do whatever it is you're doing to get your data.
    $scope.data = someService.getData(dataPage);
  });
});
```

Then in your view (HTML):

```
<div ng-controller="MyCtrl">
 <ul class="pagination pagination-sm">
    <li class="footable-page-arrow">
       <a data-page="first" href="#first">«</a>
    </li>
    <!-- below, use ng-class to set the active value of your li, based on 
         whatever dataPage was set to -->
    <li class="footable-page" ng-class="{ active: dataPage === 3 }">
       <a href="#" ng-click="dataPage = 3">4</a>
    </li>

    <!-- same here -->
    <li class="footable-page" nf-class="{ active: dataPage === 0 }">
       <a href="#" ng-click="dataPage = 0">1</a>
    </li>
    ...
    ...
 </ul>

 <!-- render out your data down here -->
 <pre>{{data | json}}</pre>
</div>
```

#### More advanced information:

What I've shown above is a "quick and dirty" solution to the problem. The most ideal solution would be to leverage updates to the URL via $location and/or links with resolved data on the routes to load the data, so your pageData would be persisted in the URL itself (and therefor retain forward/back history in the browser). The solution for that looks quite a bit different and gets into some more advanced Angular topics. For now I'd just work on mastering the approach above and look into using routing, $location and $routeParams to persist the dataPage value.

Hopefully this helps you and I wish you the best of luck.

Comment: Great answer, Thank you for all useful information.

Answer (score 2):

That is highly irregular as controllers shouldn't care about the DOM. Amongst many things, this rule helps to keep controllers **very** testable.

As soon as you begin to concern yourself with the DOM, then you move into Angular's [directive territory](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/directive).

Using the directive approach we could assign the `data-page` attribute to our controller `scope` by using the following:

```
app.directive('page', function pageDirective() {

    return {
        restrict: 'A',
        link: function link(scope, element, attributes) {
            scope.page = attributes.page;
        }
    }

});
```

Since the `scope` will be implicitly the same as the controller's scope, anything you perform on the `scope` variable inside the directive will be reflected on the controller – as long as the directive is in the controller's scope – `ng-controller`.

By specifying `scope: true` you will create a new scope for your directive which could access the controller's scope from the prototype chain, or by using `scope.$parent`. We also have `scope: {}` which creates an isolate scope and is a whole different kettle of fish.

Answer (score 0):

I recommend you always share data between your controllers and directives using a Service/Factory and injecting it on both sides.

```
app.factory('SharedService', function() {
  return {
    sharedObject: {
      value: '',
      value2: ''
    }
  };
});

app.controller('FirstCtrl', function($scope, SharedService) {
  $scope.model = SharedService.sharedObject;
});

app.directive('myDirective',['SharedService', function(SharedService){
  return{
    restrict: 'E',
    link: function(scope){
      scope.model = SharedService.sharedObject;
    },
    template: '<div><input type="text" ng-model="model.value"/></div>'
  }
}]);
```

Here is a plunkr showing how it can be done:
http://plnkr.co/edit/Q1VdKJP2tpvqqJL1LF6m

Comment: That should not be a problem, since the directive´s template (view) is disconnected from the data (at least it should be).